# Magento : How to Get Output in Phtml File From $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result))?

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers, phtml

In controller file I put this,

```
$result = "success";
$this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
```

How to fetch output in phtml file?

Comment: what exact data u want to return to phtml please specify more details

Comment: @NAGARAJUKASA - How to get controller files result in phtml file?. I have phtml file but how to call the result.

Comment: You should call this controller using ajax  from phtml then you will get that  response

Comment: @AmitBera - In phtml file I should directly call $result then it will display the result?

Comment: Yes, it will be get  json response which will give by "`$this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));`

Comment: @AmitBera - But i didnot get any response

Comment: @AmitBera - Actually its a ajax request. I think it will be called in any js file. Can you tell me how to find that js file?

Comment: let me know whether you got proper solution for u r question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i am showing you sample example using ajax request with json responsce

**Template file:**
/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/pay/index.phtml

```
<div id="results" style="width:100px; height: 200px;border:1px solid red;">
</div>

<button type="button" id="id1" class="myButton">Click Me 1!</button>
<button type="button" id="id2" class="myButton">Click Me 2!</button>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
          jQuery(".myButton").click(function() {
            var id = this.id;
            jQuery.ajax({      
            type: "POST",
            data: 'pid=' + id,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            url: "<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl().'pay/index/sampledata' ?>",
            success:function(response){                       
                if (response){

                 jQuery('#results').html(response.pid);

                }
            }

            });
        });
     });
</script>
```

**IndexController.php**
/app/code/local/Excellence/Pay/controllers/IndexController.php

```
 public function sampledataAction() 
 {
     $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
     $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($post));

 }
```

Note: Please try this code in default magento and custom module. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using the phtml file you can call the controller via ajax you just need the controllers url and then can use ajax to get the data.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/route/index/controller",
  success: function(response) {
                var result = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
  },
  error: function(xhr) {
  }
});
//do stuff with response
```